# Core data only adding data to last object

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am trying to populate core data with default data for testing, but when I do the 25 DataPoint objects that are created do not store the Meal object in their .meal property when I try to access them through fetch requests. Before the save, I have looped through the DataPoint objects and printed their .meal property which shows that the property is successfully being set for each one. However, after the save when I fetch these DataPoints, only the last DataPoint contains the meal in it's .meal set.

```
     if User.currentUser == nil {

        let newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("User", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! User
        newUser.username = "Will"
        newUser.avatar_large = UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage(named: "Karl@3x.png")!)
        newUser.meals = NSSet()

        let newMeal = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Meal", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! Meal
        newMeal.title = "BURGER AND FRIES"
        newMeal.time = NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(-24*60*60)
        newUser.meals = newUser.meals?.setByAddingObject(newMeal)

        var last = 150.0

        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        for i in 0..<25 {

            let dataPoint = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("DataPoint", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! DataPoint
            dataPoint.time = newMeal.time.dateByAddingTimeInterval(Double(i) * 300.0)
            last += drand48() * 40 * (drand48() > 0.5 ? -1.0 : 1.0)
            dataPoint.value = NSNumber(double: last)
            dataPoint.meal = NSSet(object: newMeal)

        }

        do {

            try managedObjectContext.save()

        } catch {

            print("User Save Failed")

        }

    }
```

Comment: Sounds like the relationship from `Meal` to `DataPoint` is to-one, when it should be to-many.

Comment: @pbasdf the relationship is to many, but I am not trying to add multiple meals to these objects so that isn't the problem. The problem is that all the dataPoint objects have an empty set for their meal property even though I set it.

Comment: What about the *inverse* relationship, from `Meal` to `DataPoint`?  That must also be to-many.

Comment: @pbasdf the inverse relationship does not exist. Do I need one?

Comment: @pbasdf that worked thank you!

Comment: Yes, as a general rule, you should always specify an inverse for every relationship, even if you never use it.  There are very few circumstances where you are better off without an inverse.